# I'm trying to write a program with two methods that will determine how many individual digits in an integer between 3 and 6(inclusive)

Tags: java

The help I need is in **JAVA** coding, please. I'm having an extremely hard time learning this through online class instead of in person due to the pandemic going on. Any help is appreciated and thank you for taking the time to help a struggling student/parent!

- Create a Scanner object that will be used for user input.
- Prompt the user to enter an integer and store the value in a variable named num.
- Call a method named **getCount** (details are given below) that will return the number of individual digits in the number that is between 3 and 6 (inclusive)
- Display the original number and the number of digits between 3 and 6.
- Create the method getCount that has a parameter of type int and returns a value of type int. This method will do the following:
- Declare an integer variable named count and initialize it to 0.
- Within a while or do-while loop, do the following:
- Get the last digit of the parameter by getting the remainder after dividing by 10. Use the % operator to do this.
- Call the **inRange** method, passing this digit as a parameter. If the inRange method returns true, add 1 to
  count.
- Use integer division by 10 on the parameter to change its value by getting rid of the last digit. Use the / operator to do this.
- Stay in the loop as long as the parameter is greater than 0.
- Create the method inRange that has a parameter of type int and returns a value of type Boolean. This method will return true if the parameter is between 3 and 6 (inclusive).

```
import java.util.*;
public class five {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        System.out.print("Your number is ");
    } // end main

    public static boolean getCount(int) {
        return int >= 3 && <= 6;
    } // end getCount method

    public static boolean inRange(int) {
        return boolean
    } // end inRange method
}
```

The output I'm attempting to get is

```
Enter an integer: 435678123
Your number is 435678123
It has 5 digits between 3 and 6.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class five{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your number is " + x);
        System.out.println("It has " + getCount(x) + " digits between 3 and 6");
    }

    public static int getCount(int x){
        int count = 0;
        while(x > 0){
            count += inRange(x%10) ? 1 : 0;
            x/=10;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static boolean inRange(int x){
        return x >= 3 && x <= 6;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your answer, pasting all text into the answer with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).